# conditional run trailing command in a one liner

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to conditionally run a trailing command. I have chained a bunch of bash commands together with &&. Greater than 0 run. 0 don't. The is the relevant portion.

```
mac RC=42 $ echo "abc abc" | wc -w && echo hi
2
hi
mac $ echo "" | wc -w && echo hi
0
hi
```

I'm looking for a way to run the && part when the `wc` return a count greater than 0 and not run for zero.

So you can come up with something that works in the full command.

```
find '/Users/mac/exifin/' \( -iname "*.nef" -o -iname "*.dng"  \) -type f \
 -exec sh -c "ls -l \"{}\" && /usr/local/bin/exiftool -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude \"{}\" |\
 wc -w && echo copy && cp \"{}\" '/Users/mac/exifout/' && echo  \"   Delivered\" " \;
```

I'm running this in the MacOS 10.10.5 terminal.

Comment: Why does it have to a one-liner?

Comment: What does your `find` have to do with `echo` and `wc` ? Please explain what is your actual goal

Comment: To "simply" things, I running the bash command as part of an applescript. Applescript pushes one string to the macOS shell via "do shell script".

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe into a conditional expression just like any other command:

```
$ echo | wc -w | [ $(cat) -gt 0 ] && echo hi

$ echo "abc abc" | wc -w | [ $(cat) -gt 0 ] && echo hi
hi
```

This `cat` inside [`$( ... )` command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) to get the piped input into the command line as though it were written there, and then [tests whether it's numerically greater than 0](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). The whole `[ ... ]` block returns true if it is, and false otherwise, so you can use it with `&&` as usual.

You could also use [`test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test) by name instead of as `[`:

```
$ echo "abc abc" | wc -w | test $(cat) -gt 0 && echo hi
```

You could avoid the `cat` process with `read;echo $REPLY` instead, but it probably doesn't matter.

---

In Bash, this works, and the `cat` runs at the right place and time [inside the pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines), but it doesn't in some other shells (including zsh). I don't know if this is explicitly specified behaviour, but it is stable across Bash versions back to 3.2 at least, in both POSIX and non-POSIX modes (macOS `sh` is Bash in POSIX mode). My reading of POSIX is consistent with this being the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` for this.

```
grep -qP '\S'
```

This will exit with 0 on any non-whitespace characters in the input.
- `-q` stands for quiet (no output)
- `-P` is for Perl regexes
- `\S` is for a non-whitespace character

Some examples:

```
$ echo | grep -qP '\S' && echo ok
$ echo "  " | grep -qP '\S' && echo ok
$ echo " x  " | grep -qP '\S' && echo ok
ok
```

If this is what you really want.

Comment: Didn't fly on macOS 10.10.5.  mac $ echo | grep -qP '\S' && echo ok
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
mac RC=2 $

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

```
find '/Users/mac/exifin/' \( -iname "*.nef" -o -iname "*.dng"  \) -type f  -exec bash -c 'if test -f "$1"; then if (( $(/usr/local/bin/exiftool -GPSLatitude -GPSLongitude "$1" | wc -w) > 0)); then echo copy; cp "$1" "/Users/mac/exifout/" && echo  "Delivered"; fi; fi' -- {} \;
```

You can't rely on boolean logic of `wc -v` as far as it not returning error when the output is `0`